C/C++ header cannot be read/accessed by compiler with CMake files addressing the directory containing the header
I am having an issue with the compiler not reading a header file. I am working with a one-wire library for reading the temperature on a DS18B20 using a Raspberry Pi Pico, I copied it through aa git and made a new directory for it via the command prompt using build tools. To use this library for my project I stored this in the directory C:\SDK\pico-sdk\lib\MyProjectLib\pico_one_wire where it has subdirectories that hold the source code and header file. This is separate from my project file itself to avoid clutter. I don't see much issue with this approach since I know the directories I will utilize. I am using CMake to build the project, address these directories, and target the libraries containing the header file and source code. So far I was able to address the source file one_wire.cpp without issue but the issue with the header file and the compiler remains. I get the error message on the line I stated #include "one_wire.h" which states the following in my terminal...
[  6%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/DS18B20.dir/DS18B20.cpp.obj
C:\SDK\pico-sdk\Ryan_Paye\SeniorDesign\DS18B20\DS18B20.cpp:5:10: fatal error: one_wire.h: No such file or directory
    5 | #include "one_wire.h"
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.

From my current understanding

The directory must be included in my case to access the library
directory externally.
The executable needs the correct directory and
.cpp file which it does
I could be wrong but I believe it does this through
the directory I posted. Please clarify if so

My question is, what is causing the compiler to fail to read the header while it starts to compile? I suspect it has to do with my CMake file itself, but I do not know how since I included the same directory below. Any help would be appreciated, thank you. Below is my Cmake file and Compilation results.
Here is my Cmake file below
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.13)
include(pico_sdk_import.cmake)
project(DS18B20 C CXX ASM)
set(CMAKE_C_STANDARD 11)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)

include_directories(${PICO_SDK_PATH}/lib/MyProjectLib/pico_one_wire)

pico_sdk_init()
add_executable(DS18B20
    DS18B20.cpp
    ${PICO_SDK_PATH}/lib/MyProjectLib/pico_one_wire/source/one_wire.cpp
)
pico_enable_stdio_usb(DS18B20 1)
pico_enable_stdio_uart(DS18B20 1)
pico_add_extra_outputs(DS18B20)
target_link_libraries(DS18B20 pico_stdlib hardware_gpio pico_one_wire)

Here is my compiler results with the necessary flags
Microsoft (R) Program Maintenance Utility Version 14.40.33812.0
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

[  2%] Built target bs2_default
[  5%] Built target bs2_default_padded_checksummed_asm
[  6%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/DS18B20.dir/DS18B20.cpp.obj
C:\SDK\pico-sdk\Ryan_Paye\SeniorDesign\DS18B20\DS18B20.cpp:5:10: fatal error: one_wire.h: No such file or directory
    5 | #include <one_wire.h>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: 'C:\arm\arm-none-eabi\13.3.Rel1\bin\arm-none-eabi-g++.exe -DCFG_TUSB_MCU=OPT_MCU_RP2040 -DCFG_TUSB_OS=OPT_OS_PICO -DLIB_PICO_BIT_OPS=1 -DLIB_PICO_BIT_OPS_PICO=1 -DLIB_PICO_DIVIDER=1 -DLIB_PICO_DIVIDER_HARDWARE=1 -DLIB_PICO_DOUBLE=1 -DLIB_PICO_DOUBLE_PICO=1 -DLIB_PICO_FIX_RP2040_USB_DEVICE_ENUMERATION=1 -DLIB_PICO_FLOAT=1 -DLIB_PICO_FLOAT_PICO=1 -DLIB_PICO_INT64_OPS=1 -DLIB_PICO_INT64_OPS_PICO=1 -DLIB_PICO_MALLOC=1 -DLIB_PICO_MEM_OPS=1 -DLIB_PICO_MEM_OPS_PICO=1 -DLIB_PICO_PLATFORM=1 -DLIB_PICO_PRINTF=1 -DLIB_PICO_PRINTF_PICO=1 -DLIB_PICO_RUNTIME=1 -DLIB_PICO_STANDARD_LINK=1 -DLIB_PICO_STDIO=1 -DLIB_PICO_STDIO_UART=1 -DLIB_PICO_STDIO_USB=1 -DLIB_PICO_STDLIB=1 -DLIB_PICO_SYNC=1 -DLIB_PICO_SYNC_CRITICAL_SECTION=1 -DLIB_PICO_SYNC_MUTEX=1 -DLIB_PICO_SYNC_SEM=1 -DLIB_PICO_TIME=1 -DLIB_PICO_UNIQUE_ID=1 -DLIB_PICO_UTIL=1 -DPICO_BOARD=\"pico\" -DPICO_BUILD=1 -DPICO_CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=\"Release\" -DPICO_COPY_TO_RAM=0 -DPICO_CXX_ENABLE_EXCEPTIONS=0 -DPICO_NO_FLASH=0 -DPICO_NO_HARDWARE=0 -DPICO_ON_DEVICE=1 -DPICO_RP2040_USB_DEVICE_UFRAME_FIX=1 -DPICO_TARGET_NAME=\"DS18B20\" -DPICO_USE_BLOCKED_RAM=0 -IC:\SDK\pico-sdk\lib\MyProjectLib\pico_one_wire -IC:\SDK\pico-sdk\src\common\pico_stdlib\include -IC:\SDK\pico-sdk\src\rp2_common\hardware_gpio\include -IC:\SDK\pico-sdk\src\common\pico_base\include -IC:\SDK\pico-sdk\Ryan_Paye\SeniorDesign\DS18B20\build\generated\pico_base -IC:\SDK\pico-sdk\src\boards\include -IC:\SDK\pico-sdk\src\rp2_common\pico_platform\include -IC:\SDK\pico-sdk\src\rp2040\hardware_regs\include -IC:\SDK\pico-sdk\src\rp2_common\hardware_base\include -IC:\SDK\pico-sdk\src\rp2040\hardware_structs\include -IC:\SDK\pico-sdk\src\rp2_common\hardware_claim\include -IC:\SDK\pico-sdk\src\rp2_common\hardware_sync\include -IC:\SDK\pico-sdk\src\rp2_common\hardware_irq\include -IC:\SDK\pico-sdk\src\common\pico_sync\include -IC:\SDK\pico-sdk\src\common\pico_time\include -IC:\SDK\pico-sdk\src\rp2_common\hardware_timer\include -IC:\SDK\pico-sdk\src\common\pico_util\include -IC:\SDK\pico-sdk\src\rp2_common\hardware_uart\include -IC:\SDK\pico-sdk\src\rp2_common\hardware_resets\include -IC:\SDK\pico-sdk\src\rp2_common\hardware_clocks\include -IC:\SDK\pico-sdk\src\rp2_common\hardware_pll\include -IC:\SDK\pico-sdk\src\rp2_common\hardware_vreg\include -IC:\SDK\pico-sdk\src\rp2_common\hardware_watchdog\include -IC:\SDK\pico-sdk\src\rp2_common\hardware_xosc\include -IC:\SDK\pico-sdk\src\rp2_common\hardware_divider\include -IC:\SDK\pico-sdk\src\rp2_common\pico_runtime\include -IC:\SDK\pico-sdk\src\rp2_common\pico_printf\include -IC:\SDK\pico-sdk\src\common\pico_bit_ops\include -IC:\SDK\pico-sdk\src\common\pico_divider\include -IC:\SDK\pico-sdk\src\rp2_common\pico_double\include -IC:\SDK\pico-sdk\src\rp2_common\pico_float\include -IC:\SDK\pico-sdk\src\rp2_common\pico_malloc\include -IC:\SDK\pico-sdk\src\rp2_common\pico_bootrom\include -IC:\SDK\pico-sdk\src\common\pico_binary_info\include -IC:\SDK\pico-sdk\src\rp2_common\pico_stdio\include -IC:\SDK\pico-sdk\src\rp2_common\pico_stdio_uart\include -IC:\SDK\pico-sdk\src\rp2_common\pico_stdio_usb\include -IC:\SDK\pico-sdk\src\rp2_common\pico_unique_id\include -IC:\SDK\pico-sdk\src\rp2_common\hardware_flash\include -IC:\SDK\pico-sdk\src\common\pico_usb_reset_interface\include -IC:\SDK\pico-sdk\src\rp2_common\pico_int64_ops\include -IC:\SDK\pico-sdk\src\rp2_common\pico_mem_ops\include -IC:\SDK\pico-sdk\src\rp2_common\boot_stage2\include -IC:\SDK\pico-sdk\lib\tinyusb\src -IC:\SDK\pico-sdk\lib\tinyusb\src\common -IC:\SDK\pico-sdk\lib\tinyusb\hw -IC:\SDK\pico-sdk\src\rp2_common\pico_fix\rp2040_usb_device_enumeration\include -mcpu=cortex-m0plus -mthumb -O3 -DNDEBUG -std=gnu++17 -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -fno-exceptions -fno-unwind-tables -fno-rtti -fno-use-cxa-atexit -MD -MT CMakeFiles\DS18B20.dir\DS18B20.cpp.obj -MF CMakeFiles\DS18B20.dir\DS18B20.cpp.obj.d -o CMakeFiles\DS18B20.dir\DS18B20.cpp.obj -c C:\SDK\pico-sdk\Ryan_Paye\SeniorDesign\DS18B20\DS18B20.cpp' : return code '0x1'
Stop.
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.40.33807\bin\HostX86\x86\nmake.exe" -s -f CMakeFiles\DS18B20.dir\build.make /nologo -SL                 CMakeFiles\DS18B20.dir\build' : return code '0x2'
Stop.
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.40.33807\bin\HostX86\x86\nmake.exe" -s -f CMakeFiles\Makefile2 /nologo -S                  all' : return code '0x2'
Stop.


Where exactly is the header file?

The quotes in #include "one_wire.h" tell the compiler (the preprocessor really) to look for the header inside the current directory. If the header belongs to an external library it is usually specified with #include <one_wire.h>. Many compilers will search the specified location and then search the other, incurring nothng but a small performance hit, but this behaviour is not required and thus not guaranteed.

@tkausl I saved it under C:\SDK\pico-sdk\lib\MyProjectLib\pico_one_wire\api do I need to be more specific for the directory I linked and included? Even when I put the full path for the directory the compiler failed to read the header, but the source file was just fine.

@user4581301 I just did that fix, but I am still getting the same error message.

[Edit] your question with the full compilation line being used.  We'll need to see the compilation flags that are actually being passed.

Crap. We need to get the build info out of sleek-and-sexy mode and into wall-of-text mode so we can see all of the compiler options. Try some of the answers here. Looks like you should be able to make the second -most voted answer fit your build system.

@user4581301:  You may want to state how the include paths, passed to the compiler, effect the searching.

@RyanPaye you wrote in the comment that your one_wire.h is under C:\SDK\pico-sdk\lib\MyProjectLib\pico_one_wire\api , but the include directory you pass to your compiler is C:\SDK\pico-sdk\lib\MyProjectLib\pico_one_wire, so it looks like a typo to me, api directory is missing. Side note: don't use include_directories, which will add global -IPATH flag, instead use target_include_directories(DS18B20 PUBLIC YourPathHere) (or PRIVATE, if you use the includes only in the implementation).

Adding to a target foreign source file like this: ${PICO_SDK_PATH}/lib/MyProjectLib/pico_one_wire/source/one_wire.cpp is very bad practice and is part of your problem.

edited
just use target_include_directories to add dir of one_wire.h to your target. that should fix it.
cmake does not recursively include the subdir of include path, so you have to add one by one.
and if you don't, there is also a workaround, change the path of one_wire.h to relative path to your cmake project current path. call message(${cmake_source_dir}) to print. Or change to  full path.
And if you find there are some others warnings like that, do the same again.

There is no such think as target_include_path in CMake.

my bad, target_include_directories this shoud the commad to be used

That worked for me. Can you please edit the answer if possible so that it shows the correct syntax?
